# WebView "Restricted Site" page without "Allow Website" button

Tags: ios, ipad, webview

one of our App use WebView to login to our service.
However, I just got a screenshot from one of the client showing the WebView with the

> Restricted Site
>
> You cannot browse this page at "https//xxxxxxx"

First I thought iPad has Safari restricted site set to "On", but that does not seems to be the case.
Another interesting thing is that I also tried to turn on the site restriction on the iPad I have in hand and similar error page appear

> Restricted Site
>
> You cannot browse this page at "https//xxxxxxx"
>
> Allow Website

So the different is that it have the Allow Website button.
My question is does anyone happen to know under what circumstance will the "Restricted Site" page appear without the "Allow Website" button?

Is it possible that there are some iPad profile restricting the access to the site?
Any help is greatly appropriated.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this you have to allow access to the IP of your device. In the settings you probably enabled restrictions and for "website" you set: "specific websites only". 
If you add your IP to this list it will work fine until the IP change.
I wasn't able to find a different solution when the restrictions are activated.